# SSRS Report cascading parameters

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have 3 parameters in an SSRS report. Two (Param 1 and Param 3) are drop down list of values that can be chosen from a query, (param 2) is a true/false radio button parameter. What I'm trying to do is set it up so that if param 2 - true is chosen u have to chose a value for param 3, if param 2 -false is chosen then no param 3 must be chosen.

Param 1 will always be chosen, I 'm not having any difficulty with handling that
I tried setting up cascading parameters but had no success. I have a main dataset which contains all parameters then they all have separate datasets to find available values.

Answer (score 0):

Although cascading parameters can affect the possible values of subsequent parameters, they can not make parameters required or not.

I suggest that you create a value such as `"<No Value>"` for param 3, which can be selected by default. Test for this special value in your query and ignore it if appropriate.